# Is it possible to use a method from the parent class in the overwritten version in its child in javascript?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

Is it possible to use a method from the parent class in the overwritten version in its child in javascript?

Answer (score 3):

Yes:

```
ParentClass.prototype.methodName.call(this, arg1, arg2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could call the following in the overwritten version in the child class:

```
ParentClass.prototype.methodYouAreOverwriting.call(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the module pattern check out this article: http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth